# WooCommerce Product Table Conditional styling

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooCommerce table and i want when someone adds to cart an item the entire row of that item in the table to change color. I am using a plugin for the WooCommerce table! How can i achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use jQuery unless your plugin has options to change certain elements on add-to-cart
something along the lines of this:

```
$("#co").click(function(){
   $(this).css({"backgroundColor" : "blue"});
});
```